# How to keep a string and return a variable's total with flowgortiham

Tags: flowchart, flowgorithm

In flowgorithm, how do I keep a string and return a variable's total? Then also return the remainder of total divided by another variable.

Here is what I need to complete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How do I keep a string and return a variable's total?

In the output box, type something like: "this is my string"&myVariable
See: http://www.flowgorithm.org/documentation/index.htm

> Then also return the remainder of total divided by another variable

There is a box called "Assign". In that you can assign whichever variable and use the basic math functions to do what you're asking.
See: http://www.flowgorithm.org/documentation/operators.htm